# How do I clear command prompts in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

so when you enter a command into a command block or type one in chat it shows the command in chat like if you do /kill @e it would say in chat what was killed I wanted to know how to clear that?

Answer (score 0):

/gamerule sendCommandFeedback false

EDIT: If you mean command block feedback use /gamerule commandBlockOutput false

Comment: does this delete /say commands like if you do /say (fill in blank) does it show in chat still

Comment: No, because say makes you say something and your speech is not command feedback. Sorry.